# Nginx Ingress, HTTPS, and internal HTTPs

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

So, here's what's up: We have HTTPs being handled externally by our nginx ingress on a kubernetes cluster. This is great and all, but it means any traffic between the proxy and its backing service is going over http. This is a bit of a flaw in our security coverage so we're trying to get that secondary internal traffic to travel over https as well.

Now, the ingress has a `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-secret: secretName` which should allow us to get the backend services certificates. But no matter how I setup the ca, etc, there service terminals before sending anything.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue?

Comment: As @coderanger requested, please be more specific. Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), highlight to "Help others reproduce the problem". This is very important because with a generic question, the best you can get is a generic answer that is never going to be useful to you.

Comment: That's sadly as specific as I can get. There documentation for the nginx ingress is sadly lacking

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with nginx. Your backend services must be listening on https which means they must have a server certificate as well, it's not something nginx can do for them. This is assuming you're running nginx as a layer 7 proxy. Alternatively you can run it as a tcp proxy and have clients do the tls handshake directly with backend services, but then you'd lose all the application-layer capabilities of an ingress proxy.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange  Can you elaborate on the back-end being setup with HTTPS? such as will a self signed cert be ok, ? and how to forward the request to the back-end ? like does host header need to be changed?